# Global table search react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I tried to implement global search with new material UI next table component, I have handleSearch method, which receives event, and then I use regexp to check if event.target.value the same as in table. But when I delete string in search, the columns do not update. It starts to search only I start type. How to search by number not only by string in this case?

```
const columns = [
    {
        dataKey: 'deviceType',
        label:'Device Type',
        numeric: false,
    }, {
        dataKey: 'deviceID',
        label:'Device ID',
        sortable: true,
        numeric: true,
        // cellRenderer: ({item, key}) =>
        //          <Button >Default</Button>,
    }, {
        ........
    }]

const data = [
    { key: 1, deviceType: 'Tag', deviceID: 1, name:'Tag For sending an ', location: 'Room_104', status: 'assigned'},
    { key: 2, deviceType: 'Tag', deviceID: 2, name:'Tag For sending an ', location: 'Room_104', status: 'assigned'},
    {.......},
]

class EnhancedTable extends Component {
    state = {
        selected: [],
        data,
        order: {
            direction: 'asc',
            by: 'deviceID',
        },
        search: '',
    }

    handleSearch = event => {
        debugger
        const {data} = this.state
        let filteredDatas = []
        filteredDatas = data.filter(e => {
            let mathedItems = Object.values(e)
            let returnedItems
            mathedItems.forEach(e => {
                const regex = new RegExp(event.target.value, 'gi')
                if (typeof e == 'string')
                    returnedItems = e.match(regex)
            })
            return returnedItems
        })
        this.setState({data: filteredDatas, search: event.target.value})
    }

    render = () => {

        const {data, search} = this.state

        return (
            <Paper>
                <Table
                    data={data}
                    search={search}
                    onSearch={this.handleSearch}
                />
            </Paper>)
    }
}
export default EnhancedTable
```

Comment: From what I understood you are trying to search for numbers. You can convert a number to a string in javascript.

Comment: I'm a bit confused if you're saying that you expect it to search every time you delete a character or if you want it to update the table once you delete all the characters in the search field? If the latter, it seems like you just need to update your regex to check for an empty string and if the search field is empty then return all items.

Answer (score 0):

```
 fuzzyContains = (text, search) => {
        debugger
        if (!text)
            return false
        if (!search)
            return true

        search = search.toLowerCase()
        text = text.toString().toLowerCase()

        let previousLetterPosition = -1

        return search.split('').every(s => {
            debugger
            previousLetterPosition = text.indexOf(s, previousLetterPosition + 1)

            return previousLetterPosition !== -1
        })
    }

    handleSearch = search => {
        const {data} = this.state
        // debugger
        let filteredData = data.filter(x => Object.keys(x).some(key =>
            // debugger
            this.fuzzyContains(x[key], search)
        ))
        console.log(filteredData)
        this.setState({filteredData, search})
    }
```